# How do I use event source in asp.net Boilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

How do I use event source in asp.net Boilerplate?Implement CQRS（Command Query Responsibility Segration）.

Comment: explain your issue in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABP Framework does not offer any infrastructure for CQRS at the moment.
There is an open issue on github https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/88.
You can follow this issue for future developments.